# Как поместить в массив 10 000 000 000 чисел?

Tags: java

Мне нужно сделать массив в который я должна поместить 10 000 000 000 мелких чисел. Я дошла к тому что это не возможно.

Код рабочий, если место LONG везде поставить INT. Но в int не помещается это количество чисел. Так, объясню что я делаю в этом коде. У меня есть двухмерный массив, мне нужно его отсортировать, мне кажется что проще всего будет это сделать через обычный массив и исходя из этого у меня и возникла проблема с "10 000 000 000".

Можно ли это сделать так как я планировала, то есть не особо меняя код? Если нет тогда прошу совет.

*Сложные ответы не приветствуются потому что я только начала программировать и мало что понимаю в различных функциях.*

```
int n = sc.nextInt();
int m = sc.nextInt();
if (n>=100000 || m>=100000) System.exit(0);
int [][] array = new int [n][m];
long f =n*m;
int [] arraypomoc = new int [n*m];
long poc =0;

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
       array[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
       arraypomoc[poc]=array[i][j];
       poc++;
    }
}
for (long i = 0; i < arraypomoc.length-1; i++) {
    for (long j = 0; j < arraypomoc.length-i-1; j++) {
        if(arraypomoc[j]>arraypomoc[j+1]){
            int temp = arraypomoc[j];
            arraypomoc[j]=arraypomoc[j+1];
            arraypomoc[j+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам памяти не хватит. Под 10млрд значений надо минимум 40 гб памяти

Answer (score 2):

Несложный ответ:

```
int getArrayPomoc(int [][] array, int m, long index) {
  int i = index / m;
  int j = index % m;
  return array[i][j];
}
void setArrayPomoc(int [][] array, int m, long index, int value) {
  int i = index / m;
  int j = index % m;
  array[i][j] = value;
}

void sort2dArrayAs1d(int [][] array, int n, int m) {
  long f = n * m;  
  for (long i = 0; i < f - 1; i++) {
    for (long j = 0; j < f - i - 1; j++) {
        int vj = getArrayPomoc(array, m, j);
        int vj1 = getArrayPomoc(array, m, j + 1);
        if(vj > vj1){
            setArrayPomoc(array, m, j, vj1);
            setArrayPomoc(array, m, j + 1, vj);
        }
    }
  }
}

int compareArrays(int [][] a, int [][] b, int n, int m) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
      if (a[i][j] < b[i][j]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[i][j] < b[i][j]) {
        return 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

...
int [][] a = new int [n][m];
int [][] b = new int [n][m];
// initialize arrays a and b

sort2dArrayAs1d(a, n, m);
sort2dArrayAs1d(b, n, m);
// compare arrays a and b
int result = compareArrays(a, b, n, m);
```

Comment: Вроде разобралась, все не сложно, мне нравится, но я не понимаю одно, как я могу дальше использовать этот отсортированый массив?

Comment: @NataliiaVetsko Подождите, про это нам ничего не известно. Вы написали в вопросе, что Вам надо осортировать двумерный массив как одномерный. Но зачем - не сказали.

Comment: согласна, моя ошибка. Просто не думала что можно отсортировать так, что потом не вожможно им пользоваться. И если я скажу что это мне нужно сделать для двух массивов и потом просто сравнить одинаковы ли они, много изменится?

Comment: Извините, возможно я туплю, но я все равно не могу сравнить два отсортированых массива, если я делаю это через if тогда выдает ошибку, что тип void не разрешено.

Comment: @NataliiaVetsko добавил `compareArrays`

Comment: Оно опять выдает ошибку, но в этот раз уже в  compareArrays где начинается сравнение двух массивов. Я наверное сейчас не совсем понимаю работу этого всего вместе и у меня возникает вопрос, действительно ли compareArrays в результате сравнивает отсортированы массивы?

Comment: @NataliiaVetsko "опять выдает ошибку" - какую? Да, действительно сравнивает.

Comment: Не пишет конкретно, просто доходит до места result, останавливается и пишет что из-за ошибки в compareArrays (где начинается сравнивание, где if) программа не может продолжить работу.